# Only 1 of 3 1:1 relationships will be non-null per record

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an event. This event can be set for a campaign, county, or state. It is always just one of the three. (While a campaign/county event does occur in a given state, it is not a state level event.)

```
public class Event
{
    public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }

    public County? County { get; set; }

    public State? State { get; set; }

    // lots of additional properties
}
```

So here's the questions. And this is in the context of making this all work in EF:

1. Is there a way, and any value, in telling EF that exactly one of these must be non-null?
2. Is there any way, like the old C union construct, where these three can be a single non-null property that is one of these three classes (i.e. I don't want to declare this an Object).

And if the answer to the above is no, is there any downside in EF if I create an interface that all three classes implement?

And out of curiosity (interface makes more sense in this case), is there any downside in EF to having all three extend a common base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnModelCreating` of your DbContext, you can set up a fluent constraint:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasIndex(e => new { e.CampaignId, e.CountyId, e.StateId })
    .IsUnique();
```

Comment: That's a good idea - this will enforce the constraint in the DB. Also, can I suggest you add as an option HasIndex(e => new[] {"CampaignId", "CountyId", "StateId"}) for those of use that don't like to expose our FKs in the model. Not marking as answer (yet) in case someone has answers to the other parts. But did give it +1.