# C# Union construct

Tags: c#

I have an event (party at someone's house, not a C# delegate). This event can be set for a campaign, county, or state. It is always just one of the three. (While a campaign/county event does occur in a given state, it is not a state level event.)

```
public class Event
{
    public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }

    public County? County { get; set; }

    public State? State { get; set; }

    // lots of additional properties
}
```

So here's the question. (And this is in the context of making this all work in EF)

Is there any way, like the old C union construct, where these three can be a single non-null property that is one of these three classes (i.e. I don't want to declare this an Object)?

I guess I can do an Interface they all implement but that's weaker than a union and will be a big problem with Entity Framework - not sure I can map three 1:many possibilities on one property.

This is a follow-on to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75776975/only-1-of-3-11-relationships-will-be-non-null-per-record)

Comment: Looking from a database perspective, if you want to have a direct relationship, one field maps to one table. The only way you could have it stored as one field is if Campaign, County and State are all stored in the same table. You could have a Locations table, with a Type field. When it comes to databases, figure out your tables structure first, then C# code later.

Comment: @EtienneCharland I think you're right. But figured I should ask in case there is something I'm not aware of.

Comment: If they have the same data, you could create a base class with all the properties you need as well as an indicator enum.  Then have three sub-classes whose only role is set the indicator properly.  If the data is _close, but not quite the same_, you could take an approach that the base class has all possible properties, but the sub-classes check to make sure that non-useful properties are null (or null-ish)

Comment: So you're going to store them in EF? As a TPH with discriminator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't think that's what I need although I might be wrong. The Campaign, County, & State are all models & tables in the DB that different other models have a many:1 relationship with. The Event model does too, but is unique in that only one of the three will be connected for any single event.

Comment: Right, and you can define 3 types (or one generic type) for this side of the database FK in a TPH. So that EF will only allow one FK to be specified. Even if the database table has 3 nullable FK columns. Or all FK properties map to the same column, without generating any real FK relationships.

Comment: This question of mine is relevant: [C# Equivalent for C++ std::variant (sum type / discriminated-union)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520239/c-sharp-equivalent-for-c-stdvariant-sum-type-discriminated-union)

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions - this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option for how you can model `Event` in a table-per-heirachy, with foreign keys from different tables;

```cs
public interface IHasEvent<T> where T:IHasEvent<T>{
    int EventId { get; set; }
    Event<T> Event { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Event {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Event<T>:Event where T:IHasEvent<T>{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("class")
    .HasValue<Event<Campaign>>("Campaign")
    .HasValue...

modelBuilder.Entity<Event<Campaign>>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Parent)
    .WithOne(p => p.Event)
    .HasForeignKey<Campaign>(e => e.EventId);
```